# Visual Studio 2010 Intercept Test Events

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing a Visual Studio 2010 (SP1) extension and I want to intercept the creation, execution and results from tests.

I'm considering test manipulated when one creates a "Test Project" in the wizard. I think I have to use the TestTools API, but I don't get which API to use :-(

Also it seems that the TestTools are only available in Visual Studio Premium/Ultimate, is that right??

I appreciate any pointers to the right events to intercept.
Thanks!!

Comment: Looking at support for tests without Ultimate is on my to do list as well. What sort of things are you looking to surface. Main thing I'm needing is a view of test results in the MS Build log.

Comment: I want to know when the tests are run, and the outcome of each test.